# Por que em operações de "reset" de css não é recomendado usar o asterisco?

Tags: css

Eu já vi vários tutorias de internet sobre `css reset` ensinando que não se deve jamais usar o asterísco para aplicar as modificações.

Por exemplo:

```
* { margin:0; padding:0; }
```

Porém, junto com a afirmação de que fazer isso é problemático, eu nunca vi uma explicação de **porquê não se pode fazer isso**.

Qual é o motivo do uso do asterisco no css não ser recomendado? Existe algum risco?

Comment: Talvez por performance, mas isso varia demais. Tem algum exemplo de onde leu isso?

Answer (score 3):

Usando " * " você está selecionando **TODOS** os elementos do `HTML`, o que não faz muito sentido. Um exemplo: a tag `<p>` por natureza já vem com um `margin-top` e um `margin-bottom` setados, se você retirar esses espaços muito provável que você precisará adicioná-los novamente depois, já que são os espaços padrão do parágrafo, e sem eles os textos ficarão colados.

O reset é para deixar os elementos mais "puros" possíveis, retirando qualquer influência do navegador ou algum outro resquício de `CSS`. Não deve ser aplicado à todos os elementos.

É o que eu acho, né.