# O que significa o asterisco em "* {}" no CSS?

Tags: css

Às vezes pego sites prontos pra editar e percebo que no console aparece:

```
* {
  /* código aqui */
}
```

O que significa esse asterisco?

Comment: seletor universal

Comment: Poderia explicar pra que serve?

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113970/por-que-em-opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-reset-de-css-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-recomendado-usar-o-asterisco

Comment: Me enganei @LucasCarvalho! +1 boa pergunta, achei que já tinha pergunta sobre o assunto aqui :). Isso é muito usado pra resetar as configurações iniciais do Browser. Leia [O que é User Agent StyleSheets?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/165937/o-que-%C3%A9-user-agent-stylesheets)

Comment: Pô... namoral. Só pesquisar "asterisco css" que surge 1 milhão de artigos explicando isso...

Comment: Precisa negativar Leon? Eu perguntei aqui, porque gosto da comunidade, e não vi perguntas relacionadas. Além de me ajudar, ajuda o stackoverflow, com SEO, Google, etc. Muitas outras pessoas não sabem isso. Se não quiser ajudar, não precisa atrapalhar, eu ja fui ajudado, e agora sei o que é.

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Me desculpe, mas em geral, perguntas feitas sem nenhuma pesquisa anterior são negativadas. Você teve sorte nesse caso.

Comment: Leon, você ganha algo em sua vida, negativando uma pergunta, relativamente boa?

Comment: @LucasCarvalho Aqui não é lugar para esse tipo de discussão. Mas fica a dica, o primeiro tópico: [Como fazer uma boa pergunta?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) Não considerei uma boa pergunta por que você claramente não tentou pesquisar.

Comment: @LeonFreire equivocado seu comentário. Leia esse [artigo](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4432/%C3%89-errado-perguntar-por-coisas-que-se-acham-facilmente-como-alguns-julgam-no-go) no meta. Perguntas que agregarem conteúdo ao site serão sempre bem-vindas.

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Então o artigo que eu mandei da SOPT está errado? Se sim, deveria ser editado, não? Fiz as críticas baseadas em experiências prévias e do envio deste mesmo artigo por comentários.

Comment: @LeonFreire com o perdão, mas o *"procurou exaustivamente"* se refere a procurar **dentro do site** (se clicar no link lá notará que ele vai pro buscador do próprio site), não tinha pergunta especifica sobre o assunto, quero dizer tem até uma resposta minha https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/58005/3635, mas não é muito sobre `*`, é sobre o comportamento de `.classe`, agregar "conteúdo canônico" em portugues é fundamental para tornar o nosso site uma fonte mais confiável de pesquisa.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Ok. Ainda acho que o artigo deveria ser editado para ficar mais claro. Isto não está óbvio e como eu disse, já foi usado antes. Tudo que falei aqui foi por experiência própria.

Comment: @LeonFreire não está óbvio pra você, entende? Todas as pessoas que viram, gostaram, e mesmo as que não gostaram, não precisaram negativar a pergunta, entende? Pensa comigo: Se a pergunta é legal pra outras pessoas e acrescenta algo pra essas pessoas, qual meu intuito negativar a mesma, sendo que não está ela, me prejudicando?

Comment: @LeonFreire compreendo, mas tenha em mente, que quem define o que é bom para a comunidade é a comunidade (usuários), esses textos foram trazidos de um padrão, se quer um lugar para afirmar o que a comunidade acha util e bom este lugar é o [Meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com), leia, acompanhe, participe, tem muitas perguntas e respostas em [meta-tag:comportamento] que podem lhe ser úteis. Ainda sim entendo sua atitude como boa vontade e não estou te repreendendo, dentro do entendimento você fez corretamente. ;)

Comment: @LucasCarvalho ele não fez de má fé, e já entendeu, recomendo a você também ler o [meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/), principalmente sobre o significado de down-votes, claro que tem downvote mal usado, mas dentro do entendimento do Leon, não foi de má fé, como disse, agora é ser paciente e esperar as pessoas absorverem o que é a nossa comunidade ;)

Comment: Obrigado!! @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento Entendido. Meu voto foi retirado.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`*` é chamado de [seletor universal](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/CSS/Universal_selectors). Esse seletor representa todos os elementos serão afetados pelas definições de estilo ali colocadas.

Por exemplo, eu costumo usar muito pra poder aplicar uma determinada estilização em todos os elementos da página:

```
* { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

É claro que deve-se [ter cuidado](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/113970/por-que-em-opera%C3%A7%C3%B5es-de-reset-de-css-n%C3%A3o-%C3%A9-recomendado-usar-o-asterisco) ao usar o asterisco, para não afetar configurações padrões de alguns elementos.

Observe que, no caso específico da sua pergunta, o asterisco sozinho afeta todos os elementos, mas é possível afetar apenas todos elementos que sejam filho de outros.

Exemplo:

```
p * {
   padding: 10px;
}
```

Ou seja, tudo que estiver dentro dos `<p>`, vão ter o padding de 10px.

Além disso, é possível fazer várias outras combinações com o seletor `*`, mas, em suma, ele sempre representará "todos os elementos".