# Como pegar o tamanho atual da fonte no css e aumentar

Tags: html, css, angularjs

Bom dia, alguem pode me ajudar a me dar uma dica de como pegar o tamanho atual da fonte para poder aumenta-la em seguida?
ps:
Estou usando o angularJs para as funções!

Comment: Posso perguntar porque queres aumentar a fonte? Seria caso de poderes fazer com CSS queries?

Comment: Preciso clicar no botão e fazer ela crescer ou diminuir e pode sim fazer pelo css

Comment: Ok, pensei que seria caso de aumentar/diminuir dependendo do tamanho do ecrã. Aí CSS seria melhor. Mas neste caso precisas de algum JavaScript, mesmo que o CSS faça as alterações com classes. Explica melhor então o HTML que tens e quanto queres que cresça etc...

Comment: Existe uma forma de reconhecer o tamanho da fonte via javascript?

Comment: Sim, com `window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize`

Comment: Que tal o seletor universal: [O que significa o asterisco em “* {}” no CSS?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209631/o-que-significa-o-asterisco-em-no-css)

Comment: Obrigado Sergio!

Comment: Marconi, não entendi o intuito de usar este seletor

Comment: `* { font-size: 15px}` vai aplicar uma fonte de 15 pixels a todas as tags @GabrielSouza

Comment: @GabrielSouza se deres mais detalhes do teu problema vais ter respostas mais adaptadas ao teu problema. Assim como está ainda estamos a adivinhar o que será que tens no código.

Comment: @Sergio, muito obrigado pela ajuda, consegui atingir o objetivo usando o window.getComputedStyle(el).fontSize

Comment: @GabrielSouza ótimo! Então marco como duplicada de outra pergunta parecida para ficar mais organizado.

Comment: Como outros já disseram, não está claro o contexto da sua dúvida. Mas pode ser o caso de usar unidades relativas no seu CSS, como `em` ou `%`. (CC @Sergio).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá,

Existem diversas maneiras para fazer isso, uma delas é utilizando o pseudo-seletor `focus`. Segue abaixo dois exemplos, um aumentando com `scale` e outro com `font-size`:

```css
#bt-1:focus {
  transform: scale(1.5);
}
#bt-2:focus {
  font-size: 30px;
}
```

```html
<p><button id="bt-1">Click para aumentar</button></p>
<p><button id="bt-2">Click para aumentar</button></p>
```