# ReCaptcha aparece com Scroll Bar

Tags: html, css, recaptcha, aspx

Estou a criar uma página aspx, e ao fazer o layout adicionei o ReCatcha da google, mas este aparece com uma scroll bar e eu não sei como retirar. Provavermente alguma coisa está a interferir.

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #032D63;
}

.content {
  height: 580px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  align-self: flex-end;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #032D63;
}

.title {
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #054394;
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textbox {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Submitbtn {
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Submitbtn:hover {
  background-color: #032D63;
}

.text-xs-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.g-recaptcha {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PedidosEmissaoCertifDiplomas.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmissaoCertifDiplomas.PedidosEmissaoCertifDiplomas" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title>
      <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="..." />
    </title>
    <link href="PedidosEmissao.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function RecaptchaAlert() {
        swal("Captca Not Filled!", "Please fill in the captcha code", "warning");
      }

      function EmailNaoExiste() {
        swal("Email Inválido", "...", "warning");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#f0f0f2;overflow:hidden;">
    <form runat="server" id="form1">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" class="header"></div>
        <div class="title">
          <h2 style="text-align:center">Emissão de Certificados/Diplomas</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="content" style="text-align:left">
          <div style="margin-left:5%;margin-bottom:2%;margin-top:2%">
            <img src="Images/itemV.gif" />
            <asp:Label ID="IntD" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label><br /><br />
            <table style="width:100%;">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:70px;">
                  <asp:Label ID="Email" runat="server" Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="Emailtxt" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" style="height: 10px;width:350px;" required autocomplete="off" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s].{0,}"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="height:27px"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="text-xs-center">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" ReCaptcha.SiteKey.PedidosEmissaoCertifDiplomas "] %>"></div>
          </div>

          <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:5%">
            <asp:Button CssClass="Submitbtn" runat="server" ID="btnSubmitForm" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitForm_Click" />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div style="height:50px"></div>
        <div id="footer" class="footer"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

[image: ReCaptcha com Scroll bar]

**Como posso tirar a scrollbar do ReCaptcha?**

Comment: Já tentou adicionar na classe `g-recaptcha` o `overflow-y: hidden`?

Comment: @RicardoPontual Sim ficou igual

Comment: Se é um `iframe` que vc está chamando com o Captcha vc pode colocar isso direto no iframe: `scrolling="no"` Ou então tentar via css `iframe{ overflow:hidden;}` De qualquer foma... testei aqui e no meu documento aparece sem o scroll

Comment: @hugocsl Sem fazer alterações aparece sem o scroll? Eu testei em 2 navegadores em ambos aparece-me o scroll

Comment: No Chrome não apareceu scroll não! Eu só copiei esse código ai e colei em um documento novo, sem nenhum framwork tipo bootstrap etc. ele deu foi um bug na tag pq eu não rodei no localhost abri um html normal mesmo só pra testar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ao usar sua configuração do css `*{... overflow-x...` o seletor `*` indica que deve atribuir tais estilos para todos os elementos da pagina e ao atribuir esse estilo está dando conflito com algum código que você fez ou até mesmo com algo da google para o reCaptcha. [Tópico do SOpt falando sobre o seletor* do css](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/209631/o-que-significa-o-asterisco-em-no-css)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 13px;
}

#wrapper {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #032D63;
}

.content {
  height: 580px;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 0px 0px 15px 15px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  color: black;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: white;
  margin: 0px 20px 20px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.footer {
  align-self: flex-end;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 15px;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  background-color: #032D63;
}

.title {
  vertical-align: middle;
  box-shadow: 2px 2px 2px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  border-radius: 15px 15px 0px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 30px;
  color: white;
  border: 1px solid white;
  background: #054394;
  margin: 20px 20px 0px 20px;
  padding: 10px;
}

.textbox {
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.Submitbtn {
  width: 230px;
  background-color: #ff8000;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 16px;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.Submitbtn:hover {
  background-color: #032D63;
}

.text-xs-center {
  text-align: center;
}

.g-recaptcha {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PedidosEmissaoCertifDiplomas.aspx.cs" Inherits="EmissaoCertifDiplomas.PedidosEmissaoCertifDiplomas" %>

  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

  <head runat="server">
    <title>
      <asp:Literal runat="server" Text="..." />
    </title>
    <link href="PedidosEmissao.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;" />
    <script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
      function RecaptchaAlert() {
        swal("Captca Not Filled!", "Please fill in the captcha code", "warning");
      }

      function EmailNaoExiste() {
        swal("Email Inválido", "...", "warning");
      }
    </script>
  </head>

  <body style="background-color:#f0f0f2;">
    <form runat="server" id="form1">
      <div id="wrapper">
        <div id="header" class="header"></div>
        <div class="title">
          <h2 style="text-align:center">Emissão de Certificados/Diplomas</h2>
        </div>
        <div id="content" class="content" style="text-align:left">
          <div style="margin-left:5%;margin-bottom:2%;margin-top:2%">
            <img src="Images/itemV.gif" />
            <asp:Label ID="IntD" runat="server" Text="..."></asp:Label><br /><br />
            <table style="width:100%;">
              <tr>
                <td style="width:70px;">
                  <asp:Label ID="Email" runat="server" Text="Email:"></asp:Label>
                </td>
                <td>
                  <asp:TextBox ID="Emailtxt" runat="server" CssClass="textbox" style="height: 10px;width:350px;" required autocomplete="off" pattern="[^@\s]+@[^@\s]+\.[^@\s].{0,}"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td style="height:27px"></td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </div>
          <div class="text-xs-center">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="<%=ConfigurationManager.AppSettings[" ReCaptcha.SiteKey.PedidosEmissaoCertifDiplomas "] %>"></div>
          </div>

          <div style="text-align:right;margin-right:5%">
            <asp:Button CssClass="Submitbtn" runat="server" ID="btnSubmitForm" Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmitForm_Click" />
          </div>

        </div>
        <div style="height:50px"></div>
        <div id="footer" class="footer"></div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </body>
```

Obs: tirei o seu `overflow:hidden` da tag `<body>` pois ele estava impedindo o scroll da página, impossibilitando sua visualização completa.

Espero ter ajudado, caso não consiga comenta ai que tento de novo.

Comment: Mas o scroll dele não é no eixo X, a janela do Captcha está com scroll no eixo Y...

Comment: Pois é me expressei mal na resposta, mas editei lá. Ao meu ver, ta dando conflito de algo que ele fez ou com algo da google(reCaptcha), a principio proporcionei a solução, se alguem identificar o porquê é bem vindo para editar a resposta, pois por enquanto não achei.

Comment: Se vc não achou a resposta definitiva, e não tem certeza se é isso que está ocasionando o problema, vc não acha que o mais adequado seria fazer um comentário na pergunta do que postar uma resposta que vc não sabe se resolve o problema...?

Comment: Eu sei que é isso, funcionou! tirou o scroll do captcha. Não sei falar com o que o overflow-x ta dando conflito mas ta, interpretação zero.

Comment: Cara eu tb testei aqui, exatamente com o código da pergunta, e no Chrome abril normal, nem apareceu o scroll, no meu browser pelo menos esse CSS nada tem a ver com o problema. Mas se vc diz que resolve o autor da pergunta certamente vai te dar um feedback

Comment: Ficou ótimo, obrigado!